# Show a dialog box instead of the task pane when using my add-ins

Tags: office-js, office-ui-fabric

I'm creating an Outlook add-ins and when the user clicks the add-ins icon (on the top right corner of the screen, see the screenshot) I want to show a dialog in the center of the screen instead of showing the *task pane*.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me how can I do that?

Because every time I click the add-ins icon a *task pane* is opened by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by declaring single uiless action (ExecuteFunction) in your addin manifest, and run [dialog api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) in your uiless function to show dialog in the center of screen.

Comment: I thought there were problems with Dialog API called under `ExecuteFunction`, but looks like it should be perfectly fine. The example of the project: [Office-Add-in-Dialog-API-Simple-Example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Dialog-API-Simple-Example)